# Simple Probabilities Problem - Ιndependence

Tags: statistics

I have this problem:

Possibilities:

- $A,P(A)=0.3$
- $B,P(B)=0.6$
- $C,P(C)=0.1,$ $C$ is independent of $A$ and independent of $B$
- $P(A$ and $ B)=0.2$
- F: A or B or C

Find $P(F)$

I know that it easy, but I cannot find the right solution.
Here is what I made so far:
$P(F)= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2*P(A$ and $B)=0.6$ but this answer isn't the right one.
Anny suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a $2$ in $-2\times P(A\text{ and }B)$?

Comment: This is not clear. Is $F = A \cup B \cup C$? Can you use right notations?

Comment: You are also double counting $P((A \text{ or }B)\text{ and } C)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p(A \vee B) = p(A) + p(B) - p(A \wedge B) = 0.3 + 0.6 - 0.2 = 0.7$

Consider the event $E$ to represent $A \vee B$.  Then

- $p(E) = 0.7.$
- Since event $C$ is independent of both $A$ and $B$, $C$ is independent of $E$.

It is desired to compute $p(E \vee C).$

Since $C$ is independent of $E$, $p(E \wedge C) = 0.7 \times 0.1 = 0.07.$

Thus, $p(E \vee C) = p(E) + p(C) - p(E \wedge C) = 0.7 + 0.1 - 0.07 = 0.73.$

Comment: Thnak you,that is very clear!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall your [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

For three sets that would be:

$$\Pr(A\cup B\cup C) =\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)-\Pr(A\cap B)-\Pr(A\cap C)-\Pr(B\cap C)+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$$